# Adding plain Java project as a classpath to an eclipse plugin

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-plugin

I have a plain Java project (not a plugin project) which I want to add to a classpath of a eclipse plugin which I am developing. But in web projects I can add that project as a build path and it works fine. But I tried same thing in eclipse plugin, I am able to compile successfully, but at run time I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I know OSGi quite well and I know how to add OSGi into an classpath (using export-packages) but what I want is to add Standard, non-osgi project into an classpath, so that I wont' get runtime errors. Is there anyway I can achieve this?

I can export project as a jar file or make it as a plugin project and it would work fine. But that's not my option currently because, still that API is in pre-alpha stage, and there would be lot of changes going on. So I am trying to avoid pain of exporting it as jar file everytime. Is there any option for me other than this?

Comment: Any reason why you don't make the plain java project an OSGi project?Adding the OSGi-manifest will not prevent you from using the project as a jar library in normal java applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar situation: I want non-OSGi Maven dependencies integrated into the classpath of my plugin. I succeeded with a roundabout solution, which I think is the best I could get.

I have a build step outside of Eclipse where I copy the class files of the dependency into the plugin's `lib` folder. The `lib` folder is specified in `MANIFEST.MF` as an entry in `Bundle-ClassPath` and (here comes the hack) as a **source** folder in `build.properties`. That was the only way to make the plugin work both when launched from within Eclipse and when exported.